# Is free speech declining in the Western countries?

Tags: freedom-of-speech, reference-request

#### Background

Some time ago I have watched a discussion between two professors who argued that free speech is on the decline in Western countries (examples were mostly provided for US and UK), but no clear studies references were provided.

#### Research

I tried to find out more about this topic and found the following relevant articles:

- [WashingtonPost article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/shut-up-and-play-nice-how-the-western-world-is-limiting-free-speech/2012/10/12/e0573bd4-116d-11e2-a16b-2c110031514a_story.html) (might be paywalled unless Incognito or similar is used) about limiting free speech. It provides several examples of free speech limitation in various countries (US, Canada, UK, France, Russia), but no reference for a study
- [Is Free Speech in Danger on University Campus? Some Preliminary Evidence from a Most Likely Case](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11577-020-00713-z) is a study about the free speech decline in University Campuses:

> Our results show that taking offense is a common experience and that a
> sizable number of students are **in favor of restricting speech on
> campus**. We also find evidence for conformity pressures on campus and
> that both the desire to restrict speech and the reluctance to speak
> openly differ significantly across political ideology. Left-leaning
> students are less likely to tolerate controversial viewpoints and
> right-leaning students are more likely to self-censor on politically
> sensitive issues such as gender, immigration, or sexual and ethnic
> minorities. Although preliminary, these findings may have implications
> for the social sciences and academia more broadly.

I am interested if there is any broader study about this topic for a Western country (US, Canada, UK, etc.).

Comment: Certainly on topic, but we’re going to need a working definition of “free speech”. Clearly you’re asking about a broader definition than just government censorship, but does it include people being more or less willing to express certain idea? Only political opinions?

Comment: It's also unclear if you're asking about an actual decline in free speech (relative to what time period?) vs. a question about what are the current limits of free speech. The articles you cited are about free speech today and not necessarily a decline. As for college campuses, it's hard to to compare the cited intolerance by left-leaning students today to Vietnam war protestors being shot by the national guard..

Comment: @divibisan I am mostly interested in increasing the restrictions upon free speech by the (local) governments. I have provided the reference to the University campuses study because it is the closest to what I am looking for. Not sure if it is a good fit, but [UK non-crime hate incidents](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/law-and-courts/discrimination/hate-crime/what-are-hate-incidents-and-hate-crime/) seems to be an example of the government restricting free speech since one is more easily investigated for they say.

Comment: @Cat RE: "relative to what period" I see current free speech issues often centered about internet debates. It might be the case that the difusion of speech has been made possible to unprecedent levels, which has caused all kind of discourses to be widely distributed, and those controversially cause more answers. 30 years ago anything of what I said was on record and it only reached few people, now I write regularly in sites like this. Obviously the probability of getting negative reactions to my comments is way higher now than 30 years ago, if only because more people are aware of them.

Comment: Re the study linked in the post, it lists cases as `"In 2015, a group of anonymous social science students at Humboldt-University in Berlin set up a watch blog documenting the allegedly “sexist, racist, and militarist” views of [...], a professor of political theory and well-known public intellectual."` or `students protested and publicly accused [...] of furthering “anti-Muslim racism” and “conceptual nationalism”`. Is this an attack on free speech, or an exercise of free speech on the part of the students?

Comment: As I have seen people use fact checks as an attack of free speech I am of the mind that this is vastly overblown.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a full answer, one would first have to **define** free speech. Possible definitions range from "lack of *government* censorship" (as implied by the American [First Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution)) over "freedom of expression" (as in the German [GG Art. 5](https://germanlawarchive.iuscomp.org/?p=212), where it is qualified by libel and child protection laws) to a blanket "freedom from the consequences for one's reputation" (as explained and rejected by this [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1357/) comic). With that being said:

- Many women find that expressing their views on web platforms leads to verbal abuse and threats that would certainly be criminal if they were spoken face to face. As it is, identifying the abusers is often difficult, and the police and courts are slow to take action. So effectively their freedom of speech is curtailed by impunity for threats.
- On the other side of the coin, people find that "the web" remembers things they said and did when they were young and foolish, with consequences when a prospective employer googles their name. Their freedom of speech is curtailed by being "on the record" all the time.
- On yet another side of the coin, people find a global audience for their views who would not have been published by reputable news outlets in the last century. I'm old enough to remember crackpots with blurry photocopies of densely typewritten pages, with multiple exclamation marks in place of a proper layout. Usually those handouts went into the next waste bin ...
- In places with weak worker's rights, employees might find their contract terminated if they voice controversial things, because the employer disagrees or because the company wants to protect itself from reputation loss by association.
- Many governments are using computers for surveillance that would have been impossible half a century ago. The [East German MfS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stasi) employed more than one percent of the working population of the GDR, yet they were limited by their number of analysts. Today we get things like [Pegasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_(spyware)).

So it is a mixed bag, whatever definition one adopts.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question asks whether there is a downward trend over time. If you feel that the question is too poorly defined to be answerable, then that should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @BenCrowell, there is an *upward trend* in the ability of individuals to express their opinion to large groups because no publishers are involved any more. There is a *downward trend* in the ability of some individuals to express their opinion without harassment because of that harassment. There is a *downward trend* in the ability to express opinions without job-related consequences. There is an *upward trend* in the ability to post opinions anonymously. As I said, different answers for different parts of the subject.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this really depends on what time period you're talking about, what you mean by "Western countries," and how narrowly you define freedom of speech. The Economist has [an article](https://web.archive.org/web/20180218214151/http://pages.eiu.com/rs/753-RIQ-438/images/Democracy_Index_2017.pdf?mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiWkRKbU1HWmxNVEUwTW1FdyIsInQiOiJPdlltVFV0blFRQzZNVERCZHhVeitZRElmUGplOHh3NWs1d2wzVzdRS1JvNU1kVmUxQVRESU9LbEVSOVwvR1F4aG1PV1NlS0ZZcng4NzBcLzVNZ09JOUxiZU5TTEVPekVHayttOTRqQkQ5TkNzWGNtRlowQTZ0UzlUK0pDdm9PVGlcLyJ9) that shows tabulated trends from 2006 to 2017. The title is "Democracy Index 2017: Free speech under attack," which pretty accurately tells you what the article is about, i.e., it is broadly about democracy, but it also spends some time focusing in specifically on freedom of speech. Their definition of freedom of speech is effectively defined by a list of questions at the end of the article. The free-speech questions focus on a fairly narrow, traditional definition of free speech: basically, does the government infringe on the press or cause it to self-censor?

On p. 15, they have a table that shows the changes in the democracy scores (not just freedom of speech, but freedom of speech is one of their main criteria) over time, for a period of 12 years. It's broken down into geographical blocks.

If I look at the blocks representing Canada, the US, and Western Europe, the changes are all fairly small, but 17 out of 23 countries got worse. This suggests that there has been a certain amount of gradual decay. They do discuss specific changes in these countries. These include mass surveillance, which threatens to chill free speech, and problematic hate speech laws. The UK passed an infamous "[Snoopers’ Charter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Investigatory_Powers_Act_2016)" in 2016.

If "Western countries" is taken to include Latin America, then the situation is much worse and much less stable, but it's not clear that there's any over-all trend. Venezuela has gotten much more repressive. Nicaragua's already bad situation has deteriorated. Ecuador is getting better.

The question could be improved by adding a link to the video debate and giving a brief summary so that people can see what it was about without having to watch the whole video. I suspect that the claimed deterioration in places like the US and UK had to do with fuzzy non-governmental threats to free speech, such as a tendency for people on college campuses to use the language of physical harm to talk about speech that upsets them, or a trend toward shouting down controversial speakers. These things are bad, but they aren't threats to free speech at the same level as the threats that you see in places like Turkey or Nicaragua. There may be a trend toward Western democracies providing less support and protection for people like [Ayaan Hirsi Ali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayaan_Hirsi_Ali), partly out of a misguided belief that you can't criticize violent religious extremists without being a bigot.